# Discord.js, on guildMemberAdd doesn't run every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I don't understand what's going on sometimes this works and other times it wont add people for hours and randomly start working again any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Also the GUILD Member Add does run every time it just doesn't add the role every time.

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const bot = new Discord.Client();
    const token = '';
    
    bot.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Bot is online!'); 
    })
    
    bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member");
    setTimeout(function () {
        member.roles.add(role);
        // see if they have a role
        if (member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name !== "Member")) {
            member.roles.add(role);
            console.log(member.id);
        }
    }, 3000);
});


bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Please provide more description of your code and the problem you are trying to solve. 'I don't understand what's going on sometimes this works' doesn't tell us anything about your code. Putting the name of a custom method in the title is not useful because no one knows what that is. I would recommend updating your title to reflect your problem in terms of Discord or Javascript, as that will attract experts to look at your question.

Comment: It may be because of the laggy Discord API. Try adding a delay in the member add event before adding the role

Comment: @ApocalypseCalculator I updated my code above its working better but not quite perfect, do u have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how because not much was changed in my code but this has been working flawlessly.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'TOKEN_ID_HERE';

//checking to see if they subscribed
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
})

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    bot.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID_HERE').send('<@' + member.id + '>');

    let role = member.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLE_ID_HERE");
    member.roles.add(role).then(console.log('DiscordID: ' + member.id));
});

bot.login(token);
```